# Renaming the Azure DevOps Project

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We already have Azure DevOps project and the client wants us to rename the project,before changing the name wanted to know what would be impacts since we already have the existing pipelines,agents and release is happening continuously.
Will renaming a project disturb the existing setup?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your pipeline, but unless you use the remote project repository URL in your build/release pipelines (which you probably don't), renaming should not affect your pipelines.

But be aware that the developer will have to do some changes, see: [Required user actions for working with the renamed project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/rename-project?view=azure-devops&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#required-user-actions-for-working-with-the-renamed-project)

Comment: Thanks Martin, this helps